# Does LMDB support multiple keys to same value mapping?

Tags: leveldb, lmdb

is it possible to have multiple keys mapping to the same value? If not, is there a work around for this feature?

Comment: sorry - I was out for the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible. One workaround that I use is to have the value on the second key be a pointer to the primary key. That is, the value of the second key *is* the primary key.

In particular, I make a secondary-keys table (or "Named Database" in lmdb speak) where all the *values* are primary keys in the primary table. If you look further into other database this is exactly how they implement indexes.

---

For example

```
Data table:
    key: 72E13E60-85A6-4191-A187-F6FA5D3F0975
    value: {
       "surrogate-key": "72E13E60-85A6-4191-A187-F6FA5D3F0975",
       "name": "Foo Widget",
       "location": "Atlantis Mall",
       "last-value": 892
    }
Name table:
    key: "Foo Widget",
    value: "72E13E60-85A6-4191-A187-F6FA5D3F0975"
Location table:
    key: "Atlantis Mall",
    value: "72E13E60-85A6-4191-A187-F6FA5D3F0975"
```